# How to attach a shell covering to a flat piece with clay as adhesive?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, steel, pressure

I have a ceramic nozzle type structure sort of like this:

[image: a]

The outer casing is joined with clay material with the inner ceramic nozzle. What we do is, we attach the clay in the casing, put the nozzle in base and press the casing with the help of a air press. But the thing is, we are not getting uniformity in this. The outer diameter formed with the casing is irregular. Can someone help here?

---

**SUGGESTED ONLY - PLEASE CHECK:**

See [**Tundish nozzle - CASTING - here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tundish#Casting)  = Ceramic nozzle inside outer shell - the ceramic IS attached to the base of a "Tundish" flow smoothing reservoir for molten steel which accepts molten steel from "ladles" and delivers it via these nozzles to molds.

The problem here is that the ceramic does not form smoothly against the outer shell when pressed,

Comment: Is this for forging steel (looking at the [steel] tag)?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for here.  A couple more pictures showing the process or a couple diagrams would help immensely.

Comment: @Raghav - is that your website that the image is from or from somebody eles's? Are they a competitor?